# How to let Subclass cover the inner class of the Class?

Tags: java

```
package tt;

class Out {
    class Inner {
        void print() {
            System.out.println("i anm inner1");
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        Inner in = new Inner();
        in.print();
    }

}

class Out2 extends Out{
    class Inner{
        void print() {
            System.out.println("i anm inner2");
        }
    }
}

public class Test {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Out2().run(); // 打印 i anm inner2
    }
}
```

This program prints out ("i anm inner1") now.
How can I make the program print("i anm inner2")?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588091/how-to-override-extend-an-inner-class-from-a-subclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of covering the inner class you could cover (override) a factory method in the base class, you the Out2.Inner must extend the Out.Inner

```
class Out {

    class Inner {
            void print() {
                System.out.println("i anm inner1");
            }
    }

    public Inner createInner(){
        return new Inner();
    }

    public void run() {
        Inner in = createInner();
        in.print();
    }

}

class Out2 extends Out {

    class Inner extends Out.Inner {
            void print() {
                System.out.println("i anm inner2");
            }

    }

    public Out.Inner createInner(){
        return new Inner();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either call the `print()` of the child's inner class

```
new Out2().new Inner().print();
```

Or, override `run()` inside `Out2`

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Inner in = new Inner();
        in.print();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much!But what I want to do is to cover the subclass of the father-class. How to realize it?

Comment: @user3327884 Do you mean the inner class of the base class?

Comment: Yes, I realize it following the method shown upstairs. Thank you all the same.

Answer (score 0):

you should override `run()` in `out2`

Comment: Yes, overriding can also work. But I want to reuse the run() coding part since it is so long.